# What is indirect travel?

Tags: bookings, terminology

My company uses Concur to book business travel.  I am trying to book a flight for a business trip in 2 weeks.  I have selected the flights, and on the screen where Concur asks for the project to charge the flights to, it is also asking me "Is this indirect travel?"  I am required to select either Yes or No, but I don't know what that means.

My company is off the next 2 days, and most people will be taking off for the next week due to the holidays, so I may not be able to get a timely answer from anyone there.

Comment: What does your employer’s guidance on using the system say? Is there no ‘help’ information associated with it?

Comment: It could mean an extended stay or detour because of personal reasons (tourism, visiting family/friends or similar).

Comment: Some quick googling on "concur direct vs indirect": [Webinar - Learn how to takeoff with Concur](https://go.concur.com/learn-how-to-takeoff-with-concur-travel-0719.html?pid=direct&cid=direct), [SAP Business Exchange - Travel Direct vs Indirect](https://community.concur.com/t5/Concur-Travel-Best-Practices/Travel-Direct-vs-Indirect/td-p/320#)

Comment: @Traveller The help system is not very helpful. A training video did not mention it, a link to a TravelGuide.doc resulted in a "File not found", and a search for "indirect" resulted in "No Results Found".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will need to ask your SAP/Concur administrator on this one. Typically this question is related to how the internal accounting is setup and that's different for every company.

Often "indirect" travel means its getting charged to an overhead account. "Direct" would mean it's being charge directly to a client or a project. Which one it is depends on your reason for travel and how it's getting paid.

If you can't get a hold of an admin, you should study all available manuals and documentation first. You can also ask a  trusted colleague that has traveled before. You can also try to call Concur directly but they may not know either and the'll charge for every call.

If all else fails and you can't wait, just pick one and send an e-mail to your SAP admins with the details of what you did and why. If it turns out to be wrong, in most cases any accounting issue can be fixed later without too much trouble.

Comment: Yeah, it seems more likely that this is a finance / accounting term rather than anything that's really related to travel.

Comment: +1 for "If all else fails and you can't wait, just pick one and send an e-mail to your SAP admins with the details of what you did and why. If it turns out to be wrong, in most cases any accounting issue can be fixed later without too much trouble."